# Set Content-Type Azure Blob Storage

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am currently writing a backend which takes in one or many image/video-files to be uploaded into Azure Blob Storage. I am however struggling to set the Content-Type of the files. The Content-Type is by default set to be "application/octet-stream", but I want to dynamically set them by using the file.getContentType() method.

The code looks like this:

```
    public void uploadToContainer(BlobClient blobClient, MultipartFile file) {
        try {
            blobClient.upload(file.getInputStream(), file.getSize());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //TODO:
            // Better error handling
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

Faced the same issue uploading JSON file, came up with this from stepping through the
`blobClient.upload` method you're current using:

```
        BlobHttpHeaders jsonHeaders = new BlobHttpHeaders()
            .setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        BinaryData data = BinaryData.fromStream(file.getInputStream(), file.getSize());   
        BlobParallelUploadOptions options = new BlobParallelUploadOptions(data)
            .setRequestConditions(new BlobRequestConditions()).setHeaders(jsonHeaders);
        blobClient.uploadWithResponse(options, null, Context.NONE);
```

Note this is using azure-storage-blob v12.19.0

Answer (score 1):

To set content type of a blob at the time of uploading, you will need to use the following method: [`uploadWithResponse(InputStream data, long length, ParallelTransferOptions parallelTransferOptions, BlobHttpHeaders headers, Map<String,String> metadata, AccessTier tier, BlobRequestConditions requestConditions, Duration timeout, Context context)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.storage.blob.blobclient.uploadwithresponse?view=azure-java-stable#com_azure_storage_blob_BlobClient_uploadWithResponse_java_io_InputStream_long_com_azure_storage_blob_models_ParallelTransferOptions_com_azure_storage_blob_models_BlobHttpHeaders_java_util_Map_java_lang_String_java_lang_String__com_azure_storage_blob_models_AccessTier_com_azure_storage_blob_models_BlobRequestConditions_java_time_Duration_com_azure_core_util_Context_) instead of `upload` method that you're using currently.

You will be able to define content type using [`BlobHttpHeaders`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.storage.blob.models.blobhttpheaders?view=azure-java-stable).

Comment: I'm changing from .upload() to .uploadIwhatResponse()
 I only need to add the headers, what about all the other parameters like metadata, tier, conditions, and Timeout?
It's ok if I add null? Or this will have any impact ?